# Set first table childers in TableCollection WatIn

Tags: c#, asp.net, watin

I using WatIn ,and i need to get my two  tables to TableCollection but my table have they own table inside sow when i do this

```
TableCollection Tables = MainForm.Table(Find.ById("pnlMasterDataGrid")).Tables;
```

i get return 6 tables two that  i need and they childers as well,sow i need to secelect only first two table.

How to select only first childer.

HTML code

```
<table>
<tbody>

<table>
//inside each table there more tables
</table>
<table>
</table>

</tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: Why don't you refer to index, Tables[0] and Tables[1]. Or pick based on any class/name for each table from parent table?

Comment: They don't have classes and there is not always 2 tables it can bee only 1 sow in that case if i will do Tables[1] i will get the child table of first  table

Comment: I find a temporary solution i just looking if myTable[i].OuterHtml.contains("FirstTable") text that can be only in first or second table.